# Not able to save changes after configuring the max line in IDLE Shell 3.9.1

Tags: shell, python-idle

I am new to python and computer languages.
Not able to save changes after configuring the max line in IDLE Shell 3.9.1 I want to increase Max lines written from 15 to 60 etc and SAVE changes

Comment: Seems like this setting is saved in `~/.idlerc/config-extensions.cfg` (on Linux) or `%UserProfile%\.idlerc\config-extensions.cfg` on Windows. Try checking if this file is being created or might be getting deleted for any reason.

Comment: (Corrected) In my copy of 3.9.1 on Win 10, 'Max context lines' is being saved correctly. Note that each line represents an indent and you are unlike to have code with 60 indents, and if you did, 60 context lines would leave no or little space to code to edit.